# rotating circled View with user interaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible to rotate a view as in circle form by animation in iPhone.
here to mention that must be interactive as user will interact with icons on it.. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation). For example:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

Comment: am i suppose  to import math.h file

Comment: The standard Foundation.h import covers math.h, so you shouldn't need to import it again.

Comment: Do you mean that the view isn't being rotated or that the rotation is not animated? For animation, wrap your transform with `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]` and `[UIView commitAnimations]`. More details in the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Comment: it worked thank you.. but can i make it permanent? so that it keep rotating always.. and a bit slowly :)

Comment: Yes, see `setAnimationDuration:` and `setAnimationRepeatCount:` in the above linked documentation.