# Rotate UIButton 360 degrees

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I've been trying to run an animation that rotates my `UIButton` 360 degrees using this code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
  self.vineTimeCapButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI*2))
  self.instagramTimeCapButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI*2))
})
```

However, it doesn't rotate 360 degrees because the `UIButton` is already at that location.

How can I rotate my UIButton 360 degrees?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use a trick: start rotating with 180 degrees first and then rotate with 360 degrees. Use 2 animations with delay.
Try this.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
}

UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.5,
    delay: 0.45,
    options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn
) {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 2 * .pi)
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!
Only suggestion: in order to make it a smooth 360 rotation, the delay for the second "animateWithDuration" needs to be half the size of the animation duration.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: ZERO delay should be fine!

Comment: how to repeat this for an indefinite number of times? `option: .repeat` ?

Answer (score 9):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220571/rotating-uibutton/), you can also use a `CAAnimation`. This code applies one full 360 rotation:

**Swift 3**

```
let fullRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
fullRotation.delegate = self
fullRotation.fromValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0)
fullRotation.toValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: Double(CGFloat.pi * 2))
fullRotation.duration = 0.5
fullRotation.repeatCount = 1
button.layer.add(fullRotation, forKey: "360")
```

You will need to import `QuartzCore`:

```
import QuartzCore
```

And your `ViewController` needs to conform to `CAAnimationDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CAAnimationDelegate {

}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4** version that allows you to rotate the same view infinite times:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
  self.yourButton.transform = self.yourButton.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
}
```

if you want to rotate 360°:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
  self.yourButton.transform = self.yourButton.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
  self.yourButton.transform = self.yourButton.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
}
```

Comment: This isn't working as the end position is the same as the start position.

Comment: @tobi, thanks. I never tried rotating 360° so I didn't know it doesn't work. I've updated the answer to handle that scenario.

Comment: For the 360 degree version, the second transform rotation needs to be 2 * pi. That is: self.yourButton.transform = self.yourButton.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi * 2)

Comment: @Reefwing does your suggestion work? It has been a while since I wrote the code above but I think I had some kind of issue where the button wouldn't even animate if the rotation is `pi*2` (same position at the start and end of animation). If you can confirm the `pi*2` code works, I'll update my answer. Thank you! (maybe I'll have time to test it myself later today)

Comment: @ budidino - it worked for me, although I was using an image view not a button. Note that you still need both statements like you have, but the second one needs to be pi*2.

Comment: @Reefwing I just tested and if I put `pi*2` it only rotates `180'` and the code I posted still does a `360'` for me. I'll leave it as it is for now but it's good that people can see your comment if they for some reason have the same issue as you.

Comment: @ budidino - no worries. It could be because I initialise the transform in viewDidLoad. i.e. yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0.0)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**: Animation nested closure is better than animation delay block.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
  button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi))) 
 }) { (isAnimationComplete) in

       // Nested Block
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
   button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)))
       }    
}
```

Comment: I like this solution!

Answer (score 6):

in Swift 3 :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
  button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI))
})

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.45, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
  button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2))
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also try to implement an extension which will simplify things if you need to do it multiple time

```
extension UIView {
    
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1, repeatCount: Float = .infinity) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)
        rotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
        layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
    
    // Call this if using infinity animation
    func stopRotation () {
        layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a little extension based on `CABasicAnimation` (**Swift 4.x**):

```
extension UIButton {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(.pi * 2.0)
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration

        if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
            rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate as? CAAnimationDelegate
        }
        self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

For example we can start to make a simple button:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.setTitle("Name your Button ", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Then we can build its selector:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
        sender.rotate360Degrees()
}
```

Comment: The UIView extension can only be used for elements which derive from `UIView`. It can't be used for elements such as `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: @Prashant No, you wrong. Extension are not limited as you said.Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, enumeration, or protocol type. This includes the ability to extend types for which you do not have access to the original source code (known as retroactive modeling). If you need more info about extension look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)

Comment: what I'm trying to say is your code would have to be modified a bit to be used for a `UIBarButtonItem` .  For all other UI elements that are derived from UIView, the above extension can be added. Here's how it would be for a `UIBarButtonItem` 

The line `self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)` will be modified as `self.customView!.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)`

Comment: Oh sure, that's correct, you've reason. I've update my old answer based on a old modified question (that's because we spoken about UIBarButtonItem..), now it works.

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5**. Try this, it worked for me

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
  self.yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
  self.yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi * 2)
 }
```